# By changing my permalink to postname, other pages other than the home page return a 404 error

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, permalinks

After changing all files with chmod in 777, I can't change the permalink of my wordpress site anymore, only the default permalink (simple). After this, my .htaccess file is empty.

I tried to edit .htaccess file but it doesn't work.

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions/#the-dangers-of-777

Comment: Thanks for your help @Matt, i must be carefull for the next time.